# Does single page application written in Angular2 load slowly?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

While I was reading a book about Angular2, I found a paragraph which says that with a companion of Angular2 we can create SPA. As I understand the single page application is such a website which runs mostly on client side and only do some asynchronous calls to a server when it is needed.

The problem is that, then I read a chapter about routing in Angular2 and I came up with an idea that when we got a lot of routes browser must load all components as well as static assets for all different routes when we go to a root path so it must really slow down page loading am I right?

If my guess is incorrect please explain me it.

Comment: The first page load would be slower (bc it needs to load up code that allows it to behave like a SPA), but second/third/etc page loads should be faster bc it shouldn't need to fetch as much (if any) information from the server. You could use server-side rendering to help the first page load be a bit faster.

Comment: @therobinkim How it is possible that after few times it will load faster? Does Angular2 force the loaded code to remain in cache?

Comment: No, what I meant was: in a SPA, loading `index.html` would take longer than a multi-page app... but going from `index.html` to `about.html` would take less time, bc only SOME new code will have to be fetched from the server, only SOME of the browser will have to be re-rendered, etc. I was not referring to refreshing `index.html` over and over.

Comment: Thus, Will Angular2 load all static assets as well as all components code for all different routes when user go to a root path or will it fetch the data asynchronously when it is needed?

Comment: I think Webpack handles that (which I believe is part of `angular-cli`) https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html

Comment: You can [lazy-load routes](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#lazy-load) so that you don't have to download as many components right away. Also, not all assets are immediately downloaded, only those needed for the current view.

Comment: In order to speed up your single page application you can use Lazy loading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first time you load your application will take some time (and should not take that much if you bundle things correctly), because you actually load all the app to the client (components, service files, router, etc...).

It is way more efficient and faster once everything has been loaded, because everything is already there : You don't make a server call to get your data and then display it back to the client, Angular2 does dynamically load and unload the templates based on your application (with the help of routers and all).

The only thing that can take some time is when you need to make calls to the server : Http Calls and so on. If not done correctly, these can slow down the way data is displayed on you app.

Overall, for User Experience, it's way better since everything is loaded instantly and it feels much more smoother to navigate through your application.

Comment: I totally understands that SPA loads all needed assets and resources before you can use it. This has a lot of benefits and advantage but if you are just on a login page and you are not sure yet to login. Do you need to load all resources? 

What I mean is, how can you make the login page not to load all resources and once your are authenticated that is the time the app loads all needed resources.

Comment: You can lazy-load your modules so that they will be loaded only when needed. This adds some delay as you will have to wait for the lazy-loaded ressources though.